# JAVA :Waiting for press button to get the field'text

Tags: java, button, jframe, wait

i create a menu (*window1*) where i have 3 possibilities
-when i press the first button it should open a new window *Window2.* with its funcionalities 
-i choose to press on the first button of window2 ( called *FILL*
-it opens again a new window*window3* there , i should enter a text and when i finish with i press the button OK.

The problem is : when i define the method of actionlistener of FILL i have these instructions:
             -open window 3
             -show result
and here i used a loop with a boolean until i press on OK; and if it is true i get text entered. but it doesnt work i have an infinite loop and the window is not shown please help me

Comment: And your code is where? Because your explanation stinks.

Comment: the most important part is this on : ActionListener listener1 = new ActionListener(){
             
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FILL();// open the third window and enter the text (OK to finish)

                // make waiting until OK pressed 

               showResult();get the text from the field and show it
                              
            };
         b1.addActionListener(listener1);

Comment: Instead of using anothe frame, use a modal dialog, see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details